# Import BLOBs from a CSV to an SQLite table

Tags: sqlite, csv, import, blob, uuid

How should I put UUIDs into a CSV file in order to make SQLite `.import` command to load them into table as 128-bit BLOBs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLite` is unable to import BLOBs from CSV.

The solution is to convert CSV to an SQL-statement file and execute it:

```
sqlite3 database.db < database.sql
```

If you pipe from an application, `100000`-row chunks are the most optimal amount per process instance.

If you try to pipe many gigabytes at once, `sqlite3` will crash with an `Out of memory` error.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only ways to generate a blob from the sqlite3 shell are using the `zeroblob()`, `randomblob()` and `readfile()` sql functions, `CAST`ing a value, or as a base 16 blob literal (`X'1234ABCD'`).

If your UUIDs are already represented as big endian 128 bit binary numbers in the CVS file, you *might* be able to do something like `UPDATE table SET uuid = CAST(uuid AS BLOB);` after the import. If they're a textual representation like **123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000** you could write a user-defined function to do the conversion, and using it with a similar post-import `UPDATE`.

Comment: Regarding the first case you described, I can't import 128 bit binary numbers because SQLite has no such a type. I gonna find out how to tell the importer to treat the UUID string like hex-represented binary data.